# Quarkus reactive datasource initial pool size

Tags: size, datasource, quarkus, reactive, pool

In the Quarkus documentation for reactive connections: https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#quarkus-reactive-datasource_configuration, there are configuration for the maximum size of the pool "quarkus.datasource.reactive.max-size", but for the minimum size doesn't exists.

When I start my service, the pool starts with 4 connections.

How Can I change this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The javadoc of PoolOptions](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/sqlclient/PoolOptions.html) shows that there is no option for min-size.